# TypeError: transportCtor is not a constructor in NodeRedIoTHub

Tags: node.js, azure, raspberry-pi, node-red, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send a message to my device in an Azure IoT hub. I am trying to do so using the [NodeRedIoTHub library](https://github.com/lcarli/NodeRedIoTHub) in Node-Red on a RaspberryPi running Raspbian 4.1.18-v7, NodeJS v6.11.1 and NPM v3.10.10. The message payload is according to the library's specifications and of protocol type "mqtt". When I try to send the message through the azureiothub node it gives the following error:

> TypeError: transportCtor is not a constructor

Is there something wrong with the distribution? Or am I doing something wrong in the Node Red flow? I have upgraded/installed everything running:

```
bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/raspbian-deb-package/master/resources/update-nodejs-and-nodered)
sudo npm install -g azure-iot-device@latest
sudo npm install -g azure-iot-device-mqtt@latest
sudo npm install -g node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub
```

Comment: You can check [Node-Red node for Azure IoT Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/device/node-red).

Comment: This is indeed working, thank you Rita Han